# React failing to correctly manage state on callbacks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a react native application that features some chat functionality. The pipes seem to be connected well, but something strange is happening with the state management. My state management is set up using hooks. Here's the code that manages the updates:

```
      console.log(
        'MESSAGES -()- ::',
        messages.map(m => m.text),
      )

      const gotChatEntity = (entity: MessageOrStatement) => {
        if (isMessage(entity)) {
          let mutableMessages = [...messages]
          console.log(
            'MUTABLE MESSAGES -(BEFORE)- ::',
            mutableMessages.map(m => m.text),
          )
          mutableMessages.push(entity)
          console.log(
            'MUTABLE MESSAGES -(AFTER)- ::',
            mutableMessages.map(m => m.text),
          )
          setMessages(mutableMessages)
        }
      }
```

`gotChatEntity` gets triggered whenever a chat message comes through on the socket pipeline. It seems to be firing as expected, but check out the log messages that I get. The following are the log messages from two subsequent executions of the above code.

```
 LOG  MUTABLE MESSAGES -(BEFORE)- :: ["I got the beets", "how many you want?", "1"]
 LOG  MUTABLE MESSAGES -(AFTER)- :: ["I got the beets", "how many you want?", "1", "2"]
 LOG  MESSAGES -()- :: ["I got the beets", "how many you want?", "1", "2"]
```

```
 LOG  MUTABLE MESSAGES -(BEFORE)- :: ["I got the beets", "how many you want?", "1"]
 LOG  MUTABLE MESSAGES -(AFTER)- :: ["I got the beets", "how many you want?", "1", "3"]
 LOG  MESSAGES -()- :: ["I got the beets", "how many you want?", "1", "3"]
```

Notice how in the second block of logs the chat message `2` is not in the list ever! What is going on?

It may be worth noting that the other side of the message state handling works as expected. When the user **sends** a message is works great. Here's that code

```
const sendMessage = (text: string) => {
    let message = client.sendMessage(text)
    let mutableMessages = [...messages]
    mutableMessages.push(message)
    setMessages(mutableMessages)
  }
```

No problems managing state there! Does react have some kind of weird won't update hooks in response to changes not initiated in the UI?

Comment: Please post the code that trigger `gotChatEntity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What may have happened here is when the `gotChatEntity` trigged two consecutive time, due to async nature of setState, both are executed with the same original messages state (The second one was executed before the re-render of the first call happens).

Another possible reason is `gotChatEntity` was setup in a `useEffect` hooks in a `componentDidMount` manner, which create a closure that only see the initial message state only.

In either case, to fix this, you need to use the setState using callback to retrieve the latest message.

```js
const gotChatEntity = (entity: MessageOrStatement) => {
    if (isMessage(entity)) {
        setMessages(oldMessages => {
            let mutableMessages = [...oldMessages]
            console.log(
                'MUTABLE MESSAGES -(BEFORE)- ::',
                mutableMessages.map(m => m.text),
            )
            mutableMessages.push(entity)
            console.log(
                'MUTABLE MESSAGES -(AFTER)- ::',
                mutableMessages.map(m => m.text),
            )
            return mutableMessages;
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Asked and answered! Thanks!